# How to fix form input that doesn't allow to enter field on Mobile device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm beginner in HTML and CSS, i tried to create a form which will have different field,those field are working fine on larger screen but on small screen(Mobile) those field doesn't allow to enter anything

I use inspect tool in Firefox to trouble shoot the problem ,but i don't see wrong

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row"></div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="card" style="border-radius: 10px;">
                               <h2 class="card-title" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px"> registration</h2>
                                 <div class="card-body">
                                    <form action="#" method="POST" id="insertgroup1" class="form-horizontal">
                                       <div class="form-body">
                                         <h3 class="box-title">Group details</h3>
                                           <hr class="m-t-0 m-b-40">
                                             <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                 <div class="form-group row">
                                                     <label class="control-label text-right col md-3">Group name</label>
                                                       <div class="col-md-9">
                                                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name='group_name' placeholder="Group name" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>
                                         </div>
                                   </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
```

Comment: may be there is another element overlapping the field, and not allowing you to tap over it. try to find that.

Comment: You have to debug your code as @AwsmeSandy said . Are you sure do you need all of div nested?

Comment: I tried to debug but i don't see where this overlapping occur.,if you don't mind can i share a link of a form so you can help me to troubleshoot thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe try it on another browser?

because it works with me

Comment: I tried on different mobile device , it doesnot work but it work fine only in window phone